# IE8 Jquery UI bug half time

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a website using JQuery UI DatePicker.
Fully working on the most of browser.
But there's some properties on IE8 that make my calendar not working.

the bug : I click on my datePicker and the box show with the right month, all the style is there, but none of the button working. Like theres no code/event behind them.
This error is only on some IE with an higher security.

I use a new VM with a IE more secure. I start the site in local. I have the same problem.

it took me a while to see a problem because the most of the user of the site dont have any problem (using IE8).

On my test, All js all include in local and seems to work(test for ie trusted website).

Comment: What errors do you see in your console?

Comment: "it took me a while to see a problem..."  and it will take us an even longer while to see the problem if you don't provide code examples.

Comment: Do you have a valid doctype? IE can default to Quirks mode on LAN sites if there is no doctype.

Comment: @apsillers - I dont have any error on the console.

Comment: @nullability <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @Derek Henderson for the moment, I dont know what I should give, its simple $("input.calendar").datepicker({ ... });. because it working most of the time, I search why the security of some IE8 cause the problem. if the date picker didn't show up it give the a hit, but its buttons inside the picker that doesn't working.